# Remove file name after htaccess redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to display a static HTML file in place of our existing homepage file temporarily. For example, instead of the homepage loading this:

```
http://sitename.com/
```

I have it set to load this:

```
http://sitename.com/filename.html
```

just for the homepage with the following rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /filename.html [L,R]
```

However, when this page loads for our homepage, I want to show this in the browser address bar:

```
http://sitename.com/
```

What do I need to add to my rules to hide the filename for the homepage URL? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE SOLUTION: For WordPress Users**

While the below answer did work for what we asked, we found we could no longer log into the backend of our WordPress website when we used DirectoryIndex. Our solution ended up being the following in the .htaccess file, above the WordPress block:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^$ /special-ali-funeral.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: you'd need to do `R=301` to force a client-side redirect. otherwise it's a purely internal apache-only change, and will never be visible to the client.

Comment: Thank you chris85. Can't believe I missed that. Want to answer the question for me so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive you are looking for is [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). This will load whatever file you specify when the root is requested.

e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/
```

with

```
DirectoryIndex filename.html
```

in your configuration will load

```
http://www.example.com/filename.html
```

in the background.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a rewriterule for this, use DirectoryIndex directive with relative index path

```
DirectoryIndex filename.html
```

This will internally redirect your homepage to **/filename.html**